# What us the difference between closure and prototyping in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am checking the **closure and prototype** in JavaScript. I write two **basic HTML return functions**, basically they both return the same output. Is their any difference/relation between this two and why we should use closure?

```js
//Closure
function createLI(tags) {
  return function(...args) {
    if (args.length > 1) {
      return args.map((iteam) => {
        return "<" + tags + ">" + iteam + "</" + tags + ">"
      })
    } else {
      return "<" + tags + ">" + args + "</" + tags + ">"
    }
  }
}

var tag = createLI('li');
console.log(tag('test'));



//prototype function

let Newfunction = function(x) {
  this.content = x;
}

Newfunction.prototype.aswrapper = function(...args) {
  if (args.length > 1) {
    return args.map((iteam) => {
      return "<" + this.content + ">" + iteam + "</" + this.content + ">"
    })
  } else {
    return "<" + this.content + ">" + args + "</" + this.content + ">"
  }
}

let heading = new Newfunction('h1');
heading.aswrapper('sometextprint');
console.log(heading.aswrapper('sometextprint'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you use a closure to create an object, there's a copy of their methods (they are in memory as independent objects of type `Function`, even if they do the same). If you use the prototype approach, no matter how many objects you create, there will only be a copy for each of its methods (the one of the prototype).